# Junit specific testing question on methods

Tags: java, testing, junit

I had an existing codebase with a few junit tests. Recently I added getshape() into the explain shape method. Now the unit tests aren't passing because get shape affects the result. How can I update the unit test to pass. Is their any way to have junit do nothing for that new method I added even though getshape is within explain shape?

```
//existing junit tests
Shape shape = new Shape();

//existing test
testShapeMatch(){
shape.updateShape()

assert(2, shape.size())
}

//Actual code (simplified)
updateShape{
    explainshape()
}

explainshape(){
    //do something
    getShape();
    //do something else
}

getShape(){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: so, you changed the functionality of the explainshape method, you'll need to update the tests accordingly. If you don't understand that calling getshape will have an impact, you shouldn't be coding, first try to understand the concepts of what you are doing.

Comment: You've changed the behaviour of the code, therefore you need to change the tests that check that behaviour, that's precisely *what* JUnit is for!